# SHRINKFILE Failure - Why does increasing file size resolve it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, shrink, dbcc

I am running some `SHRINKFILE` operations to clean up a bunch of tiny, unnecessary files in a filegroup. For one of the shrinks, the command below results in an error:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'myfile' , EMPTYFILE)'
```

> File ID x of database ID x cannot be shrunk as it is either being
>   shrunk by another process or is empty

It is not empty nor being shrunk. It is being run on a database not currently in use by anyone except myself. Auto shrink is not enabled and never was. However, there *were* manual shrinks performed on this database on a regular basis prior to me getting my hands on it, if that matters at all.

On [SQLServerCentral](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/515417/shrink-fails-with-error--File-ID-of-database-ID-cannot-be-shrunk-as-it-is-either-being-shrunk-by-another-process-or-is-empty?PageIndex=1), a thread from a decade ago suggests adding a few MB to the file because that "resets an internal counter or switch that tells it it's not in the middle of a shrink now."

This worked - awesome. But can anyone explain with greater detail how/why this works in regard to SQL Server internals?

Comment: Couldn't tell you the answer, but upvoting as that's a handy trick to know if I ever run into this situation in the future!

Comment: if you can repro maybe some flag on the file header page that gets set during a shrink?

Comment: Yeah I might give that a shot on a test instance, but this was prod so definitely don't have the luxury of trying to reproduce it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I poked around in the file header page, as suggested by Martin Smith in the comments.  I think this is part of the answer, but it's mostly speculation based on observing changes to the file header page flag values between performing shrinks and other operations.

---

First I created a database to test with, including a secondary filegroup:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Shrinkfile_Test]
ON PRIMARY
(
    NAME = N'Shrinkfile_Test',
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\Shrinkfile_Test.mdf',
    SIZE = 8192KB,
    FILEGROWTH = 65536KB
),
FILEGROUP [SECONDARY]
(
    NAME = N'ShrinkFile_Test_Secondary',
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\ShrinkFile_Test_Secondary.ndf',
    SIZE = 1024KB,
    FILEGROWTH = 65536KB
)
LOG ON
(
    NAME = N'Shrinkfile_Test_log',
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\Shrinkfile_Test_log.ldf',
    SIZE = 73728KB,
    FILEGROWTH = 65536KB 
)
GO

USE Shrinkfile_Test;
GO
```

The I looked at "page 0" for the secondary file, which is file_id 3:

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604);
GO
DBCC PAGE (N'Shrinkfile_Test', 3, 0, 3);
```

There's a field called `m_flagBits` that has a value of `0x208`.

If I empty this file:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'ShrinkFile_Test_Secondary' , EMPTYFILE);
```

That `m_flagbits` field stays the same (`0x208`).  Not that interesting, but now I'm in the situation you reported: if I try to empty the file again, I get this error:

> File ID 3 of database ID 19 cannot be shrunk as it is either being shrunk by another process or is empty.

I'll try growing the file (the solution that worked for you):

```
ALTER DATABASE ShrinkFile_Test
MODIFY FILE
(
    NAME = ShrinkFile_Test_Secondary,
    SIZE = 1025KB
);
GO
```

Now `m_flagbits` is `0x8`!

At this point, emptying the file again is successful returns the value to `0x208` as you might expect.

The thing that I find interesting is that if I do this after growing the file back out (AKA flagbits value is `0x8`):

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [Shrinkfile_Test] MODIFY FILEGROUP [SECONDARY] READONLY
GO
```

The file is marked as `is_read_only` in the `sys.databases` table, and `m_flagbits` is set back to `0x208`.  **So it appears there is some similar file-level flag set when shrinking a file and when setting it to read only.**

My best guess is that this value is used along with some other (internal) flag to indicate that a file is eligible to be shrunk.  Growing the file appears to un-set that flag (at least the one visible in `m_flagbits`).